# Why can the drain of a transistor be used as an output port in both OTA and TIA?

Tags: analog, ota

In OTA, the output is current. It should deliver a constant current to the next stage. So the output impedance of an OTA should be high. As the impedance seen at the drain is also high, it is understandable that the drain would be chosen as the output node of an OTA.

On the other hand, for TIA, it should give a constant voltage to the next stage. So the output impedance of a TIA should be low. However, as mentioned previously, the impedance at drain is high, so I don’t understanding how the drain can still be used as an output port in TIA?

Thanks

Comment: In what TIA circuit are you seeing a drain terminal being used as the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output impedance of the transistor's drain alone is not the same thing as the output impedance looking into the drain, with the transistor biased and connected in a feedback structure.

Here's our simplified five-transistor operational transconductance amplifier:

[image]

As you can see, the output impedance of this device is very high. If you attempt to inject a test voltage onto the output node, the very small observed current will be primarily associated with channel-length modulation (i.e. \$r_{out}\$ in the small-signal model) of the two transistors on the right branch.

Let's now put this structure in feedback, to create a simple trans*impedance* amplifier:

[image]

Looking at the drains of the transistors on the output branch *in isolation, away from the remainder of the circuit*, one could argue that the output impedance is high. However, the output impedance of the circuit cannot be derived by considering those transistors in isolation. A key takeaway is that *feedback may change, and often does change, the input and output impedances in a system*.

Let's now apply a hypothetical test current to the output node while the input is nulled, in order to find output impedance. To simplify, I will assume that the gain of our original operational transconductance amplifier was very, very large. Because the nulled output looks like an open circuit, our simplified circuit looks like:

[image]

It is then relatively easy to show that the voltage, \$V_{out}\$ will rise very little. Note that because the resistor \$R_F\$ leads to a gate, it can have no DC current flowing through it, and \$v_{in-} = v_{out}\$ under our condition of having the original input nulled.

As long as the amplifier continues to remain within its working limits, any current injected into the output node would raise the inverting input's voltage slightly. The large gain from the 5T-OTA will increase the drain current of the bottom-right transistor (and decrease drain current of the upper-right transistor), thus maintaining a near-constant output voltage.

As you can see, we have achieved exactly what we set out to: we have shown that a simple operational transconductance amplifier has a high output impedance in its simplest configuration, but an added feedback structure brought its input and output impedance to near-zero in order to achieve the design goals of a transimpedance amplifier.

Answer (score 0):

A CMOS opamp example (LMC660) spec sheet shown below has output impedance higher than you might expect...open-loop gain drops in half when loaded with 600 ohms rather than 2000 ohms.
 In comparison, a bipolar opamp with emitter-follower output stage might have open-loop output impedance no higher than about 100 ohms, and open-loop gain is more constant when loaded:
[image: LMC660]

In a fed-back circuit, whose closed loop gain is far lower than 100k, output impedance becomes much lower and looks much more like a voltage source for this LMC660. Having excess gain available can cure many ills. But at high frequency, where open-loop gain drops off, output impedance does go up, becoming  a less-ideal voltage source.